# How to install cuda (nvidia driver) silent mode with powershell?

Tags: powershell

How to install cuda (nvidia driver) silent mode with PowerShell?

I tried and it didn't work:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\User\...\Downloads\cuda_9.2.148_win10.exe" -ArgumentList "-s compiler_9.2" -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Comment: _"it didn't work"_  What happened?  Did you get any error message?  Does the installer have any logging you could turn on and check?

Comment: it close after start @@